# Using a vector data structure - design and syntax questions

Tags: c++

I have some basic C++ design/syntax questions and would appreciate your reply.

- I have N number of regions
- Each region needs to store information about an object "element"

i.e. I want to achieve something like this:

`region[i].elements` = list of all the elements for region i.

**Question 1:** 
Does the following syntax (see code below) / design look correct. Am I missing anything here?

**EDIT**

*The instances of struct elem are created by some other class and its memory deallocation is handles by that class only I just want to access that object and its members using reg[i].elements list (vector)  ... so, how should I add these element objects to the vector "elements" in class Region?*

//Already have this stucture that I need to use

```
struct elemt {
  int* vertex; 
  int foo1;
  double foo2;
};


class Region{
   public:
      // I am not sure what should be the syntax here! 
      // is it correct?
      std::vector <elemt*> elements;      
}

// Following is the constructor of "class A"
A::A(){
    // --header file defines: Region *reg;
    // Let numOfRegions be a class variable. ( changes based on "Mac"'s suggestion)
    numOfRegions = 100;
    //allocate memory:
    reg = new Region[numOfRegions];
}

A::~A(){
  delete [] reg;
  reg = NULL;
}

A::doSomething(){

// here I want to append the elements to the vector
// Let i be region 10. 
// Let e1 be an element of "struct elemt" that needs to be added

  reg[i].elements.push_back(e1);

}
```

**Question 2:** 
Is the syntax in `doSomething()` correct? Later I want to run an iterator over all the elements in `reg[i]` and want to access, `e1->foo1, e1->foo2` and like that.

**Question 3:**
In do something method, how do I ensure that e1 is not already in the "elements"

**UPDATE**

Corrected some syntax errors, and hopefully fixed memory leak noticed by user 'Mac. '

Comment: Where is Question 1? :-)

Comment: sorry I didn't make it 'bold'.. will do that :-)
Question 1: Does the following syntax / design look correct. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: btw, for syntax checking, you have a guru sitting right in your computer: the compiler!

Comment: If you're allowed to use `std::vector` then why use a dynamic array for the regions? I'd recommend a `std::vector<Region>` instead.

Comment: Thanks Manuel! Is the following syntax  correct?: std::vector <elemt> elements;

Comment: Yes that syntax is perfect. But if I were you I would use the identifier "Element" rather than "elemt". Much more descriptive and readable IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all get rid of the memory leak from the code.

```
A::A(int numOfRegions = 100){

    m_reg = new Region[numOfRegions]; // define Region *m_reg in the class 
}

A::~A(){
  delete [] m_reg;
  m_reg = NULL;
}

You are allocating memory in the constructor and storing return address in local variable and it ll get destroyed when its scope is over .

You should store the base address so that you can delete it .
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? It is a good answer that identifies a major flaw in the OP's code and offers a solution

Comment: hi Mac.. sorry I didn't understand. I am just using numOfRegions to define the total size of the Region object array. i.e. I am using just the 'value' of numOfregions... isn't it?

Comment: Your code is fine *except* that you must store your pointer in a member variable of your class (what Mac calls `m_reg`). Otherwise you'll end up with a memory leak and a useless class. Anyway, as I said in another of my comments you should really use a `std::vector<Region>` instead of manually managing the memory.

Comment: thank you very much Manuel. Your comments are really helpful.. I have updated my original question to fix this. ( and yes, I will be using std:vector<Region> ... it is not updated in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know if two elements are same or not?

From your question about detecting if e1 is already there in elements, It seems like a map/set/hash might be a better data structure than a vector.

Also, I believe it is push_back, not pushBack.

Comment: the element 'number' is known and is unique. So, I know that info. could you please illustrate how to implement the alternate data structure that you are describing? thank you!

Comment: @memC - the easiest thing is probably to use a `std::set<Element>`. You'll have to overload the < operator for your class for that to work. Check this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214295/is-it-impossible-to-use-stl-map-with-struct/

Comment: @Manuel: I would recommend providing a comparison functor type to the `std::set` unless there is a real ordering among `element` objects. That is, `operator<` has implicit semantics for people that read the code, and that might be confusing if there can be more than one order criteria in the domain. (In a phone database, people could be ordered by user id, driver license or by phone number, what should `operator<` implement?)

Answer (score 1):

You should detach the syntax from the design question. Syntax is something the compiler will check, and enforce, but then again you might get unwanted semantics...

Focusing on the design, what are your requirements? (Sorry I tend to read diagonally if there are more than a couple of lines, so I might have missed something there)

There is a class that creates/destroys `elemt` objects, is dynamic allocation really a requirement? or is it just because the elements are constructed with data available in the constructing class? If dynamic allocation is a requirement, then it looks like `elemt` objects should be held by pointer (probably smart pointers). Does the class that is meant to delete the objects keep track of them, or does it just handle the objects to the outside world expecting user code to call a deallocator function? Are the `elemt` objects shared among different entities? And there are other issues that you should consider...

Maybe you should try to reword your question, the code you posted basically is syntactically correct (just check with a compiler, I did not), but without knowing what you really want to achieve, you cannot really ask whether that is a good or bad design. Describe your real problem and then ask whether the code can be a solution to your requirements.

Comment: thanks David. The **elem** objects are handled by the class that creates them. Now, "Dynamic allocation really a requirement? " This is something I am confused about.   Need to think. Don't know when to use "new" ...what is its importance.. BTW, I have implemented a better version of this (thanks to Manuel) ... std::vector<Region> reg and then the instances of Region are added to this vector as reg.push_back(Region(num))

Comment: @memC: without a context is hard to help with design decisions. As an example, if using a `vector<Region>`, then it means that keeping different copies (as compared to shared objects) is fine, and that controlling the lifetime of the objects is not really a one class responsibility... Higher level descriptions of the problems usually give insights into this type of design decisions.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask for syntax, I can spot a missing semi-colon right away.

Also, public data (such as elements) is not really recommended. Instead, try to use getter and setter functions.

The numOfRegions variable aught to be `const int`, not just `int`. Also, feels off to declare it in the c'tor instead of in the class declaration, as it is a tuneable setting. As soon as you want to iterate over reg, you'll need to redeclare it if you keep it as now.

As for question three, you will simply have to check to see if you can find it. You will probably need an `bool operator==(const elemt &, const elemt &)` to be able to do that conveniently.

Comment: If we're going to list syntax errors, look at how he defines A's destructor. I would recommend the OP to pass his code through a compiler before he posts it here.

Comment: hi e8johan, sorry, I have corrected several of those syntax errors. Is this syntax correct: std::vector<elemt> elements; ??

Comment: memC, std::vector<elemt> is correct, but judging by the section in italic in the original post, I'd say that it doesn't do what you expect. If instances of elemt are created and disposed of elsewhere, you don't want a vector of elemt copies. A vector of pointers to the already existing instances of elemt is enough., thus: std::vector<elemt*>.

Comment: Nikola .. excellent suggestion... that is exactly what I needed to know

Comment: @Nikola: If I am using vector<elemt*>, in that case, does the following syntax still valid?  reg[i].elements.push_back(e1);

Comment: @memC - Depends on how you define e1. If it's a pointer to an Element and as you say in your question the Element object is handled by some other class, then yes. In fact it's valid *now* but it wasn't before you turned "elements" into a vector of pointers

Comment: @Manuel -- yes, it is a pointer to an element. so I will correct this declaration in the Original question.