# How to make a variable name without creating an array in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm asking a question similar to this, but with python 2.7 instead. I know that I'm the same asker of the question, but the answer should be different. Here's the link.

[How to make a variable name without creating an array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461895/how-to-make-a-variable-name-without-creating-an-array-in-c)

I looked up Data Structures on the python website, but I have no idea what they're talking about. Any help or guidance appreciated!

Comment: as like your other post I find this unclear, are you talking about an associative array type of data structure like [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: It's like a unique id that I can refer to in order to create unlimited instances and check all of them automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a structure that is similar to `std::map` in **C++**, you should use `dict`. It is a dictionary, that can have any hashable object as key (a string, a tuple, an integer). For example:

```
x = dict()
x['a'] = 5
x[6] = MyObject()
```

As you can see this is more powerful than `std::map`, because keys might have different types and values too.

If you want to assign a class, you also can do this:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

x[1] = MyClass
```

but maybe you are interested in having an instance of this class? This also is possible (on the same `dict`):

```
x[1] = MyClass() # this creates an instance
```

Comment: You may have the answer that I'm looking for, but one more thing. Lets say I have a class that was assigned to x[1], could I do this: x[1].var = 1, or is there a different way to do that?

Comment: I was more interested in instantiating a class. Thanks!

Comment: Actually assigning a class as a value in dict is pretty cool too, but I can't image the usage at the moment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In general the data structure you are looking for is a key-value mapping. Depending on language or library the name for this structure will likely be on of the following: dictionary, hash table, associative array, hash. Those are the common names though.

In python they are called dictionaries. And are created with `{}`. Whereas a list in python would be created with `[]`.

A basic example would be this:

```
a={}
a[5]='a'
a[3]=0
print a
Output: {3: 0, 5: 'a'}
```

Answer (score -6):

You could do something like the following:

```
globals()['foo'] = 10
```

or

```
locals()['foo'] = 10
```

And then you can access foo by its name after that. From your other question, it seems like your asking how do you make an array (in Python, it's usually a list) without using square brackets.

Unlike C/C++, you do not need to declare the type of a Python variable, so you can do something like:

```
foo = []
```

or

```
foo = list()
```

Where the variable named 'foo' references a value with a list (like an array) type.

Comment: No. Just No. This is wrong on so many levels in python. You don't ever play with locals or globals.