# std::map, custom key type with sorting only on one variable

Tags: c++, dictionary, operators, std

I have a key type:

```
struct KeyT {
    uint32_t timestamp;

    // example!
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t c;
    uint32_t d;
    uint32_t e;
    // ...

    bool operator== (const KeyT& key) const
    {
        if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b == key.b && d == key.d && c == key.c && e == key.e)
            return true;
        return false;

    }
    bool operator< (const KeyT& key) const
    {
        if(timestamp < key.timestamp)
            return true;
        else if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a < key.a && b < key.b && c < key.c && d < key.d && e < key.e)
            return true;
        else if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b < key.b && c < key.c && d < key.d && e < key.e)
            return true;
        else if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b == key.b && c < key.c && d < key.d && e < key.e)
            return true;
        else if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b == key.b && c == key.c && d < key.d && e < key.e)
            return true;
        else if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b == key.b && c == key.c && d == key.d && e < key.e)
            return true;
        // ..
        return false;
    }
};
```

Now, I don't really care about the sorting on member vars a, b, c, d, e, the only thing I want to ensure is that the map is sorted on timestamp. I also just realized that if I have two instances of KeyT one, two, where everything is the same except for "d", then both one < two, and two < one would be false. The only way to fix that is to write comparisons for all possible combinations of all member variables.. I'm fairly certain I'm missing something obvious, so what's the best solution in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have identical items then "one < two and two < one" will always be false by definition. Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: They aren't identical, they differ in member variable d.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this does what you need:

```
bool operator< (const KeyT& key) const
{
    if(timestamp != key.timestamp) return timestamp < key.timestamp;
    else if ( a != key.a ) return a < key.a;
    else if ( b != key.b ) return b < key.b;
    else if ( c != key.c ) return c < key.c;
    else if ( d != key.d ) return d < key.d;
    else return e < key.e;
}
```

This is a sensible if ugly pattern to use whenever you have a prioritised list of variables you want to sort on within a comparable class.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I knew I was missing something obvious.

Comment: Glad to be of service. I've written that a few times. By the way, [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) can be used for this sort of thing. It has an ordering function in `tuple_comparison.hpp` which does this prioritised, element-by-element ordering. I often use it for quick and dirty sorting of data without needing to write a new class or ordering function.

Comment: I would pack it to `std::binary_function` class and add it as a template parameter.

Comment: @Naszta: I don't see how that would make it any less verbose?

Comment: @KimSun-wu: [this is the reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609937/what-is-the-benefit-of-inheriting-from-stdbinary-function-or-stdunary-funct).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should compare only the next current key that has not been compared for being less than, and drop the `else` after `return`, like this:

```
bool operator< (const KeyT& key) const
{
    if(timestamp < key.timestamp)
        return true;
    if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a < key.a)
        return true;
    if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b < key.b)
        return true;
    if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b == key.b && c < key.c)
        return true;
    if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b == key.b && c == key.c && d < key.d)
        return true;
    if(timestamp == key.timestamp && a == key.a && b == key.b && c == key.c && d == key.d && e < key.e)
        return true;
    // ..
    return false;
}
```

If you need to compare only the timestamp, leave the first `if`, and delete the remaining ones:

```
bool operator< (const KeyT& key) const
{
    return timestamp < key.timestamp;
}
```

When you use this operator for comparing your keys, the items with identical timestamp will not be reordered.

Comment: This works too, but does it provide anything over Alex's answer?

Comment: @KimSun-wu No, it's simply a different way of writing the same condition. It may be a little more natural to read, because it can be translated to a human language in exactly the same terms as people tend to think about resolving ties in sorting orders, but other than that the two should produce identical results.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find Alex's version simpler/more intuitive to read.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is the timestamp, and the other attributes just don't matter, you can use the following which is a strict weak ordering. You'll just never know what order the objects of the same timestamp will appear:

```
bool operator< (const KeyT& key) const
{
    return timestamp < key.timestamp;
}
```

If you need to order on all the attributes I suggest `boost::tie`:

```
bool operator< (const KeyT& key) const
{
    return boost::tie(timestamp, a, b, c, d, e) < boost::tie(key.timestamp, key.a, key.b, key.c, key.d, e.key);
}
```

Comment: The first won't work, because std::map considers two objects equal if 1 < 2 && 2 < 1, which would be true if the timestamps are equal but they differ elsewhere.

Comment: @Kim Sun-wu By saying `Now, I don't really care about the sorting on member vars a, b, c, d, e` you've said that as far as the map is concerned such objects *are* equal. You can still use `operator==` to confirm that the object matches one you expect. I probably simply misunderstand your needs. Do you need to be able to have the `map` directly find an exact match for a given key object as well as be sorted primarily by timestamp?